# Can I get vim to install bundles and close in the background?

Tags: vim, docker

I've been playing around with Dockerfiles, and in setting up a development environment, there is one manual step I haven't been able to work around yet. To install the bundles in my vimrc, I have to open vim, and then it downloads them all and says to press enter to continue. I would like to do this step as a RUN command in the Dockerfile. I've tried using `vim -c 'q'`, which runs the command `:q` when vim opens, but the auto bundle install script still requires pressing enter, and it doesn't work anyway, as vim complains that the input and output are not to a terminal.

I would like to do this with Dockerfiles, rather than images

Here is the section of my .vimrc that seems relevant

```
    " Setting up Vundle - the vim plugin bundler
        let iCanHazVundle=1
        let vundle_readme=expand('~/.vim/bundle/vundle/README.md')
        if !filereadable(vundle_readme)
            echo "Installing Vundle.."
            echo ""
            silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle
            silent !git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle ~/.vim/bundle/vundle
            let iCanHazVundle=0
        endif
        set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
        call vundle#rc()
        call GetBundles()
        if iCanHazVundle == 0
            echo "Installing Bundles, please ignore key map error messages"
            echo ""
            silent :BundleInstall
        endif
    " Setting up Vundle - the vim plugin bundler end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this problem more easily solved by having my plugins listed in a separate file, `vundle.vim`. This avoids plugins and `.vimrc` settings which don't play nicely in [Ex mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes#Ex-mode).

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" Add plugins
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
" ...
```

Then you can run the install in ex mode as below.

```
vim -E -u NONE -S ~/.vim/vundle.vim +PluginInstall +qall > /dev/null
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work with my default .vimrc, which works well for my use case. I just added this to my Dockerfile, and now everything works: `RUN vim -E -u NONE -S ~/.vimrc +qall`

Comment: I'm getting a 1 exit code from the answer above. It looks like it's installing the plugins, but then exiting with a 1. `ERROR: Service 'edit' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c vim -E -u NONE -S ~/.vimrc +PluginInstall +qa' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: @plasticide I get the same error. For now I just added `|| true` to the end to suppress it. I'm not quite sure why this happens.

Comment: @MichaelMior that workaround works - I'm curious what the cause of the error is.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the great answer. I just have a quick question: in my vimrc I had `vundle#begin()` instead of `vundle#rc()` Is there any major difference?

Comment: @vabada I don't use Vundle anymore, but it probably has simply changed since I posted this answer.

Comment: Can I ask what you have moved to in place of Vundle?

Comment: @Vorticity I'm using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). I've found it's faster and also has a few more features.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution for installing plugins with vundle quietly in the background and then printing a message upon completion in the same shell:

1. Make sure the vundle repo is downloaded:

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git $HOME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

2. Set up a .vimrc file to work with [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start).
3. Run this command in your bash shell. It will run vim from the command line as a background process. When it's finished installing all the plugins to ~/.vim/bundle, it will issue a CTRL-C signal to the shell that launched it and then print a message letting you know your plugins are ready.

```
((TEMP=$(vim -E -N -u /tmp/myconfig/.vimrc +PluginInstall +qall; echo -e "kill -INT $$; echo '''\033[31m
\n================================================\n
VUNDLE PLUGINS HAVE FINISHED INSTALLING/UPDATING 
\n================================================\n\033[37m'''; 
"); bash -c "$TEMP" ) &)
```

Note: the CTRL-C command will cancel any foreground process you might have going on. This is so that you get a clean prompt after the message is printed. If you don't like that, then remove `kill -INT $$;`, but beware that the message will get printed in the midst of your foreground process and can look messy/confusing.